# List all the files for current date from a present working directory into a new file

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to get the filenames for all the files listed in my current directory for current date and list them into a new file in same path.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /queues/intermediate/outbound/*EXP_GP_$(date %Y-%m-%d)* do  f1=`basename $file`
if [ -f "$file" ];then
        cat >> All_Name $f1;
else
    echo "no files to collect"
 done
```

Comment: How does the posted code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: Hi Scott, Not sure I am new i tried a logic saying that all the files in that directory loop it doing a for all the files getting the name one by one and storing it in a variable and each time appending it in a file name All_Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /queues/intermediate/outbound/\*EXP_GP_$(date +%Y-%m-%d)\*
do

f1=`basename $file`

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cat >> All_Name $f1;
else
    echo "no files to collect"
fi

done
```

There was also a 'fi' missing.

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 | grep -v bash | grep / | sed 's/\.\///' > FileList.txt
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.